# Can the Intel Edison MCU be used without the standard Yocto linux?

Tags: microcontroller, ros, yocto, openembedded, intel-edison

Is it possible to use the MCU on the Intel Edison without having the standard Yocto Linux installed? 
At the moment I have downloaded the specific Eclipse MCU SDK and have been using that to program the MCU on the Edison. I have the newest version (from Intel's website) of Yocto on the Edison as well.

If I switch to e.g. Emutex's Ubilinux will I still be able to use the MCU in any way? With or without the standard Eclipse MCU SDK?

The main reason I want to switch to Ubilinux is to have an easier time using ROS (Robot Operating System), but this is not strictly relevant to the question.

Comment: it is just a processor that runs whatever code is loaded, so from that perspective you can run whatever you want.   Now what is available and what are you willing to port, that is another story.  If you are looking for other already ported stuff, that is what google is for not stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The Quark core runs its own Zephyr based OS, but I do expect some sort of support to be required on the Linux side too for intercommunication between CPUs. As dwelch said, the required drivers might be there for Ubilinux too.
If you are specific about ROS [someone](https://communities.intel.com/thread/56585?tstart=0) is working on [adding it](https://communities.intel.com/docs/DOC-23494) to Yocto. A quick google search also returned an unfinished project of [ROS on Edison](http://blog.csdn.net/u011070641/article/details/48894919).

Comment: It's other way around. Zephyr is a (open sourced) successor of Viper.